# What could cause this "clustered index seek" to take so much time

Tags: sql-server

My questions is **What could cause this "clustered index seek" to take so much time?**

`actual no of rows --435206`

`estimated no of rows -1`

no of executions 60336
estimated no of executions 7789

click on this link to see execution plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJEOwszLH

Comment: Without also seeing your query and maybe some data we cannot help you.

Comment: Please share your table structure and your query

Comment: and please share your query plan (use this website : https://www.brentozar.com)

Comment: If you need help understanding the execution plan, upload the plan xml to [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question. A large difference between estimated and actual counts often indicates statistics need to be updated. Execute `EXEC sp_updatestats;` to update stats for all tables in the database with default sampling.

Comment: I shared quey plan use this link to see the plan

Comment: clink this link https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkZOWPz8S to see the quey  plan

Comment: I presume you mean the *non* clustered index seek on `[APS_Adhoc_Inventory].[dbo].[SITE_INVENTORY_DAILY_Profield].[IX_CNUMBER_CNAME_QTY_ITEM_DT] [A]` that takes `23mins 18` - so about 70% of the elapsed time. 

 You need to look at the residual predicate on `CONVERT(varchar(20),[DATE_LOADED],112)='20190731'` as the seek reads `1,275,359,972` rows across all executions but only `435,206` match that predicate.. You would want to include that as an index key column and make the predicate sargable so it can be part of the seek

Comment: I added Date_loaded field in Index key column but there is no improvement in Query Plan

Comment: Please see new Plan here https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJEOwszLH